# Calculate the number of students who passed - what should I put in the if statement?

Tags: java

The idea is to add students to an arraylist, work out the number of students who have passed, and return that number.
I think I'm nearly there, as the code works, but it always returns the same value for the amount in the array list - and obviously, that is incorrect. 
I have been doing this for hours now, and I can't see what the missing statement within the if statement is to finish it off! I would be soo grateful for this!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Course
{
    private ArrayList<Student> people = new ArrayList<Student>();

    //Add a students mark
    public void add( Student s )
    {
        people.add(s);
    }
    //Return the number of students who passed (mark>= 40)

    public int pass()
    {
        int size = people.size();
        int i = 0;
        int result = 0;


        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {   
            Student s = people.get(i);

            if(s.getMark() >= 40);
            {
               // what's here?
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could change the title to make it more descriptive of the problem?

Comment: Will not compile (see the `for` loop)

Comment: @Johannes: What's syntactically wrong with the `for` loop? I'm not seeing it...

Comment: You should read your code line by line asking why you have written it, there's some extra lines that could be removed. For variable like i, you could put the value on paper and make it change. The mistakes will flash

Comment: @cHao, see the edits! The original form of the loop was `for ( i = 0; i = 40)`, @Nick fixed this...

Comment: @Johannes: The only version i see that had that flaw was yours.  :)  Apparently either it was self-fixed before you finished editing, or there was some freaky edit issue.  Like, perhaps, everything between the `<` in the `for` and the `>` in the `if` getting parsed as an HTML tag, which is bound to happen when you use `<pre>` instead of Markdown to format your code.

Comment: @cHao, crazy, you're right! I think there really was a problem with HTML interpretation... I'm sorry and thanks to all of you fixing my bad edit :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the number of students who passed an exam](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328528/finding-the-number-of-students-who-passed-an-exam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this statement inside pass method

```
ArrayList people = new ArrayList();
```

Because of this statement, when pass method is called, your local variable hides instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a duplicate, empty `people` list in the `pass()` method. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You create an `ArrayList` with no elements, and then create `result` of type `Object[]` from it, which will be of length 0.

```
    ArrayList people = new ArrayList();

    Object result[] = people.toArray();
```

Thus, your for loop will not be executed at all.

You probably want to access the instance variable `people`, you can do it by

1. Removing the `ArrayList people = new ArrayList();` from the method
2. using `this` in creating the array: `Object result[] =
   this.people.toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you specify `ArrayList people` twice, once, outside of the pass method, and the second inside of the pass method. The pass method default uses the one inside of it, which is empty.

Answer (score 0):

mark is always `0`. So this does not work:

```
if ( mark >= 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the result after you've finished the for loop, and you should be increasing `result` instead of `i`:

```
public int pass()
{
    int size = people.size();
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {   
        Student s = people.get(i);

        if(s.getMark() >= 40);
            result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```